# Orocommerce Delete an Entity

Tags: database, entity, orocommerce

I wanted to delete the entity I created with Entity Management before, but it was just disabled, and then I made changes that I could not remember in the database related to this entity and sometimes I am having problems with this entity while updating the schema.

Is it possible to do this entity hard delete in orocommerce?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do this entity hard delete in orocommerce?

From the management console, you can only soft-delete custom entities.

To hard delete, it is required to [write a schema migration](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/bundles/platform/MigrationBundle/#bundle-docs-platform-migration-bundle) that uses `Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Migration\RemoveTableQuery`.

For example, here is the migration that drops an event entity and the related database table:
https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/4b2efdbd33792df7fb0da9831b184838591f00b4/src/Oro/Bundle/NotificationBundle/Migrations/Schema/v1_5/DropEventTable.php#L48-L49

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will go with this.